# I want to call the appshell with a button but the app crashes XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to create a back button from a content page to the main page, but the app crashes, i've tried with popasycn, navigation remoe, etc, is there some way to call the app shell from a button?

```
public void OnRegClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Do you tried Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(); ?

Comment: It worked perfectly man, so much thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: @Anand could you please put it as an answer.